# Will there be an update path from Loki to Juno?

Tags: updates, release-juno

From what I can see, this isn't available as part of the Juno beta, but is it expected in the final release?  Would be nice not to have to reinstall from scratch.

Comment: It's uncertain at the moment. Take a look at this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16199/12115).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there won't be. The devs said there's plans to add it on future releases but not right now.