# system doesn't start - hangs on a process

Tags: system

I can not turn on computer anymore. I tried to update my [release-loki](/questions/tagged/release-loki) to [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) manually. Something may have gone wrong. I just see a bunch of process starting and started but this hangs with,

> A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up.

Its been almost 2 hours like that.
Please help. How can I get back to the OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade from Loki to Juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15674/upgrade-from-loki-to-juno)

Comment: elementary OS doesn't support rolling release like ubuntu. So best practice is to make a clean install of the system. You can end up with broken system if you try to update it manually, which I don't appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to rollback changes when upgrading from Loki to Juno. This is because it is impossible to upgrade from Loki to Juno from within the system like upgrading on Linux mint. The best method of updating from Loki to Juno is backing up all system files and does a fresh installation.